# Modify SQL view in GeoServer dynamically based on user

Tags: geoserver

I have an application that makes request to GeoServer db store layers to fetch Geography information. The problem I'm trying to solve is that each user has different permissions and hence I need to modify the SQL view dynamically where the user id can be passed in the SQL view within Microsoft SQL Server.

[image]

In the Java code, I wish to gain access to the GeoServer's internal user context so that I can utilize in the classes in the screenshot and use the internal GeoServer user and dynamically modify the sql at run time based on the user. Is there already a user context available in the SQL Server plugin which I can use to achieve this or is there a way on how I can pass the user context to the SQL view after the authentication in GeoServer?

Something like:

```sql
If user A: 
SELECT GeographyID, UserName
FROM   Geography
WHERE  UserName = '%geoserverUser%'

If User B:
SELECT g.GeographyID, g.UserName, c.CountryName
FROM   Geography g
JOIN Country on c.GeographyID = g.GeographyID
WHERE  UserName = '%geoserverUser%'
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the exact RDBMS in use.

Comment: Hey Vince,
Thanks for the suggestion. Edited the question. I'm using MS SQL Server for the datastore layers

Comment: "Exact" includes the version, though this seems an XY Problem for focusing on the use of "views" when it's more of a query issue. If you had connected as a user, you could use a data source that did not specify table ownership, so that each user could have their own table. But because you don't have different users in the database, that option is not present.

Comment: No, this is not a database/query issue. Sorry if my question is not clear. I have edited it with more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: you could use the start up script to set a variable that is used in the view even if you don't use session authorisation.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your reply but I would want to rewrite a sql query at run time based on the user, so it doesn't help if we have access to user at session creation time. Is there a way to get the user context at run time when the view executes?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlsession.html should do exactly what you want without adjusting GeoServer's source code.

You can set a startup SQL that is executed on every DB connection like `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION ${my_db_user}`

The variable `my_db_user` can be injected externally via the `env` url parameter like: `...&env=my_db_user:johndoe;name2=value2&...` (see [details](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html#variable-substitution-in-sld))

Be aware that this mechanism might have some security implications that should be handled with care.